# Ricci-Flat Riemannian Symmetric Spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups

I am having trouble finding information about the curvature of Riemannian Symmetric spaces. In particular, are there any such spaces that are Ricci-Flat? Assuming the spaces are simply-connected and irreducible is ok. The case I am most interested in corresponds to dimension 7.